# Unable to show multiple remainders

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am developing small reminder app it working fine but my problem is i am adding multiple reminder

**ex**
(1) 20-Aug-2013 - 7(hour) -35(minute)
(2) 20-Aug-2013 - 7(hour) -36(minute)

my reminder app shows only the second never shows the first.

my source code:

for get time and message:

```
public void onDateSelectedButtonClick(View v) {
    int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = datePicker.getMonth();
    int year = datePicker.getYear();
    int hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
    int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
    message = message_text.getText().toString();
    title = title_text.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message+ ""+title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    calender.set(year, month, day,hour,minute,0);
    ScheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(calender);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notification of day"+ day+"/"+ month, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Display message at the time:

```
private static int NOTIFICATION = 1;
private void showNotification() {
    CharSequence title = "Alarm";
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    CharSequence text = "Notification";
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon,text,time);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowActivity.class);
    String body = TaskReminder.title;
    String message = TaskReminder.message;
    intent.putExtra("title", body);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    PendingIntent pi= PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION, intent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, pi);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION++, notification);
    stopSelf();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this link for creating the reminder application. It will give the solution for what you will expect.

[Reminder Application example](http://android-developersspott.blogspot.in/2012/08/reminder-activity-task.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION++, notification); with a ++?
essentially, you are setting it to 2 yourself

Comment: i can't understand what can i do now i want to remove the ++ or someother.